# How to store music tabs in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a tablature website and I wonder which is the best way to store tabs in the database.
Here is an example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------0------------------------------
-------------1-0---------------------1-0-----------0-1-1-1-----3-1-0-----------------------
0-0-0-2-2-2------2-0-----0-0-0-2-2-2-----2-0---0-2-------------------2-------2-0---0-------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------4-2-0-----4---------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which kind of search should the database support? Consider that a lot of people on Stack Overflow do not play guitar...

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the nature of a tablature. For example, is it read from left to right? What is on the "x" and "y" axis? do you wnat to support only 6 strings or also other numbers?

Comment: Knowing a bit about guitar, dont you think you would need more things to the tabulature as you move on? Long hold? Hammer ons? Sliding? Pull? Include a better tabulature example which is generic, so you can get suggestions, that will work for you in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, and it is exactly that way, (I. E. 1-2-3) I'd go for the following:

```
Create table tabs (
Songid varchar(36) -- uuid or name, fk to the song 
String int,  
Position int
)
```

Depending on the server side language, you could theoretically retrieve and display them, separated by the dashes.

It'd be a bit tricky to get right, but what you would want, is to have a while loop or cursor display the number, or dash if there is no number at the given position, for the given string.

Does that make sense? I can try and elaborate, but it would depend on the language the web server was using.

Comment: This looks terrible. (Am I missing something? ) So this is 1 row per song, or N rows per song? What about spaces?

Comment: Effectively, there are 6 strings, each of which may, or may not have a note (number)  at a given part in the horizontal axis. So string is 1-6. If there is a note at position 1 for string 1, it displays it. Otherwise it's a dash. This is done for each of the 6 strings until the max position is reached. I can elaborate my idea using something like php if it'd help clarify.

Comment: I perfectly know how the tabulature looks like. ( I play a bit of guitar ). I was specifically asking about the database setup that you suggestion. How many rows per song? 1? N?

Comment: @Kishor from what he's showing, it's clearly N rows per song. What is so terrible about this? It obviously, as you point out above, needs some more stuff (index position, type [for stuff like spaces], etc.), but generally is on the right track, no?

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃 yes. It would be n rows per song depending on how many notes there are. An index would certainly be useful. My idea is that only notes are stored in the database, and rests are handled by the server business logic.

Comment: Since this is going to be some sort of blog with posts ( pretty obvious from the question ) it would be really handy really if everything was in a row.( Thats how all the CMS treats their posts.) Wouldnt this be a better setup, the whole thing stored as a string, with a token which says the string. six6-five7-space-four5.That would be how I would be doing this obviously unless there is something wrong with that approach. Any thoughts? Am all ears. I didnt really mean this is terrible, I accidentally typed that out. I like the idea of keeping a post together than split unless there are issues.

Comment: Since its a blog type website, that would probably have an editor to edit the already entered tabulatures. I just had that in mind as well.

Comment: Fair enough! Constructive criticism is helpful in the right context. It could definitely be held as a long string. That would definitely cut down on excess rows! Hey, feel free to submit an answer! As it's a pretty broad question, there's probably plenty of "correct" answers so I'd be interested to see them! Good to get another take on things and debate the pros / cons!